# Recording IP addresses and corresponding organizations in Python

Tags: python

I want to record a range of IP addresses and the corresponding organization using that ip address. So is there any python script which can do the same for me???

Comment: google `IP reverse lookup`

Answer (score 0):

Python offers [GeoIP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GeoIP/) library for doing  IP data lookups. You might need to buy a commercial geo ip data file though, otherwise lookups are limited to country/city level.

For recording the IP address there is too little information in your question. How you get the IP address and where you want to record it?

Comment: I have a range of IP addresses and i want to know that a particular IP address is used by which company......like i know that IP address 134.170.0.0/16 is used by Microsoft....like wise i want to what IP address is used by other companies....If i provide an IP address can i get back the company's name which is using it by any script or program??? Thank You....